# Combine 2 spf records

Tags: dns, spf

I have 2 SPF records which I don't know how to combine.

`v=spf1 a mx ip4:145.111.11.11 ~all`

`include:_spf.mijnwe.nl`

I have too many doubts if I do it correct.

`v=spf1 a mx ip4:145.111.11.11 v=spf1 include:_spf.mijnwe.nl ~all`

Comment: Oke I think it should be: v=spf1 a mx ip4:145.111.11.11 include:_spf.mijnwe.nl ~all
Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an optimal combination:

```
v=spf1 ip4:145.111.11.11 a mx include:_spf.mijnwe.nl ~all
```

You want to put literal IPs first as mechanisms are tried left to right, they are fastest for receivers to resolve, and they don't count towards your lookup limit.

Comment: Thank you! Will change this :)

Answer (score 0):

v=spf1 a mx ip4:145.111.11.11 include:_spf.mijnwe.nl ~all